# Looking for second opinion on the validity of findings drawn from this simple localized performance test under any other different setting

Tags: performance, delphi, testing, comparison, delphi-xe

**My setting**:

- OS: Windows 7 SP1 (32 bits)
- Ram: 4 Go
- Processor: Intel Pentium D 3.00 GHz
- Delphi XE

**My simple test**:

I performed a test running the following program:

```
program TestAssign;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Diagnostics;

type
  TTestClazz = class
  private
    FIntProp: Integer;
    FStringProp: string;
  protected
    procedure SetIntProp(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetStringProp(const Value: string);
  public
    property  IntProp: Integer   read FIntProp write SetIntProp;
    property  StringProp: string read FStringProp write SetStringProp;
  end;

{ TTestClazz }

procedure TTestClazz.SetIntProp(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if FIntProp <> Value then
    FIntProp := Value;
end;

procedure TTestClazz.SetStringProp(const Value: string);
begin
  if FStringProp <> Value then
    FStringProp := Value;
end;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  stopw1, stopw2 : TStopwatch;
  TestObj: TTestClazz;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  //
  try
    TestObj := TTestClazz.Create;
    //
    try
      j := 10000;

      while j <= 100000 do
      begin
        ///
        /// assignement
        ///
        stopw1 :=  TStopwatch.StartNew;
        for i := 0 to j do
        begin
          TestObj.FIntProp := 666;
          TestObj.FStringProp := 'Hello';
        end;
        stopw1.Stop;

        ///
        /// property assignement using Setter
        ///
        stopw2 := TStopwatch.StartNew;
        for i := 0 to j do
        begin
          TestObj.IntProp := 666;
          TestObj.StringProp := 'Hello';
        end;
        stopw2.Stop;

        ///
        /// Log results
        ///

        Writeln(Format('Ellapsed time for %6.d loops: %5.d %5.d', [j, stopw1.ElapsedMilliseconds, stopw2.ElapsedMilliseconds]));

        //
        Inc(j, 5000);
      end;
      //
      Writeln('');
      Write('Press Return to Quit...');

      Readln;
    finally
      TestObj.Free
    end
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**My (provisionnal) conclusion**:

It seems that:

- It's worth using Setter with property under some condition
- The overhead of calling a method and performing a conditional test take less time than an assignement.

**My question**:

Are those findings valid under any other diffrent setting or just localized ones (exception)?

Comment: Did you compiler settings allow automatical inlining of setter code?

Comment: What does your program do if assigning to properties is the bottleneck?

Comment: Then look at disassembly and you'll see why described phenomenon appears :)

Comment: @David Heffernan: I want to have a clearcut opinion on everything regarding assigning to properties and fields through hands on experiment before undertaking something else serious: Studying delphi OPF/ORM open source projects.

Comment: @ user539484: Do you mean that it depends on implementation details reflecting somewhat a design choice?

Comment: Unless you have a _real_ performance problem that needs to be solved then using a setter is _always_ the way to go.  In this specific case the setter performs _better_ due to the fact that it's not bothering to reset the same string each time. This concept is used throughout the VCL in property setters for this very reason: to avoid doing unnecessary work.

Comment: @user539484: Compiler implementation details to be precise.

Comment: @user Inlining isn't the issue in fact. The code in the Q does not result in the setters being inlined. When that is forced with `inline` directive, they run even faster.

Comment: @menjaraz, well, you already accepted your explanation on why it run faster. I;m not really convinced by it.

Comment: @user539484: You can still post a new question to keep the ball rolling, can't you?

Comment: @ NullUserException: You can put everything which differ from the context I run the test so long as they are relevant: OS, processor, build config, update pack, installed, ram size...

Comment: @menjaraz, nope, yesterday i wrote proper benchmark (yours is quite obfuscated on the loops side) and i've got t(field) ≈ ½ × t(method). For strings you were right, there are compiler specifics which will cause string constant to be copied from .data to heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the following observations:

1. The decision as to whether or not to use a setter should be based on factors like code maintenance, correctness, readability rather than performance.
2. Your benchmark is wholly unreasonable since the `if` statements evaluate to `False` every time. Real world code that sets properties would be likely to modify the properties a reasonable proportion of the time that the setter runs.
3. I would expect that for many real world examples, the setter would run faster without the equality test. If that test were to evaluate to `True` every time then clearly the code would be quicker without it.
4. The integer setter is practically free and in fact the setter is slower than the direct field access.
5. The time is spent in the string property. Here there is some real performance benefit due to the optimisation of the `if` test which avoids string assignment code if possible.
6. The setters would be faster if you inlined them, but not by a significant amount.

My belief is that any real world code would never be able to detect any of these performance differences. In reality the bottleneck will be obtaining the values passed to the setters rather than time spent in the setters.

The main situation where such `if` protection is valuable is where the property modification is expensive. For example, perhaps it involves sending a Windows message, or hitting a database. For a property backed by a field you can probably take it or leave it.

---

In the chatter in the comments Premature Optimization wonders why the comparison `if FStringProp <> Value` is quicker than the assignment `FStringProp := Value`. I investigated a little further and it wasn't quite as I had originally thought.

It turns out that `if FStringProp <> Value` is dominated by a call to `System._UStrEqual`. The two strings passed are not in fact the same reference and so each character has to be compared. However, this code is highly optimised and crucially there are only 5 characters to compare.

The call to `FStringProp := Value` goes to `System._UStrAsg` and since `Value` is a literal with negative reference count, a brand new string has to be made. The Pascal version of the code looks like this:

```
procedure _UStrAsg(var Dest: UnicodeString; const Source: UnicodeString); // globals (need copy)
var
  S, D: Pointer;
  P: PStrRec;
  Len: LongInt;
begin
  S := Pointer(Source);
  if S <> nil then
  begin
    if __StringRefCnt(Source) < 0 then   // make copy of string literal
    begin
      Len := __StringLength(Source);
      S := _NewUnicodeString(Len);
      Move(Pointer(Source)^, S^, Len * SizeOf(WideChar));
    end else
    begin
      P := PStrRec(PByte(S) - SizeOf(StrRec));
      InterlockedIncrement(P.refCnt);
    end;
  end;
  D := Pointer(Dest);
  Pointer(Dest) := S;
  _UStrClr(D);
end;
```

The key part of this is the call to `_NewUnicodeString` which of course calls `GetMem`. I am not at all surprised that heap allocation is significantly slower than comparison of 5 characters.

Comment: Great! +1 for the 2 last paragraphes.

Comment: Actually, 2) appears to be completely bogus.

Comment: @user539484: I think David meant that the benchemak is biased. Due to the if protection, the assignement occured only once during a run in contrast to what happened in the case of direct assignement to a field.

Comment: @menjaraz, conditional statement takes time too. In the fact, field writes takes ≈ 2 times less time than setter writes. I still not found how your benchmark managed to find <strike>such fast neutrinos</strike> so large difference (string?)

Comment: @DavidHe, theories, theories. I already figured what it is not an issue in the general. Also, you are assuming what reading is times slower than writing, nonsense. Hint: strings are only masking the process we (or at least i) are trying to study.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I LOLD. Now you are drawing ad personam card. You are still the same. Didnt you just stated what writing is not an issue due all constants? I'd better just rate your post and go away becauses you managed to satisfy the OP somehow w/o actually explaining why benchmark give bogus result (method should be slower than field)

Answer (score 0):

Put 'Hello' const into a variable and use it for setting then do a test again

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My intent was not to seek to optimize the program. Assigning a constant string (managed type) within a loop is part of my requirements.

Comment: But still it can be added as test cases (assign a string variable respectively to a field and a property). That is left for the reader as an exercise.